# Xcode view controller transition animations are running really slowly

Tags: ios, xcode

So, I was playing around with Xcode a bit, and a couple hours ago, I started noticing that all of my transition animations when switching between views, and first loading the app, are running really slowly. When I say slowly, I mean the initial switch between the launch screen and the first view controller taking about 10 seconds to fully finish. Has anybody else heard of this happening? I have closed and restarted Xcode many times, and I am convinced that it has *nothing to do with my code*.

Please help! It's driving me nuts!

Comment: The iOS simulator has an option called "Slow Animation" that is activated by ⌘T, which may be enabled. IIRC, there used to be a similar option for connected real devices.

Comment: @TristanSeifert good thinking!!!

Answer (score 2):

iOS Simulator -> Debug -> Slow Animations,
close.